# The cURL command from the Cloud Composer documentation is not returning any results

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I was reading the documentation "Access the Airflow REST API" (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-api?hl=en) and the cURL command that should return the client_id is not returning anything in the terminal.

The command is as follows:

```
curl -v AIRFLOW_URL 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -o "client_id\=[A-Za-z0-9-]*\.apps\.googleusercontent\.com"
```

I've tried putting in the variable AIRFLOW_URL for where my Cloud Composer is hosted and nothing.

[image: The cURL command from the Cloud Composer documentation is not returning any results.]

There is no output in the terminal, not even an error message. The cURL is executed and nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using Airflow 1?

Comment: did you literally print the value instead of AIRFLOW_URL? because if it's a variable it needs `$AIRFLOW_URL` but I suppose you knew that

Comment: @PoalaAstrid My Airflow version is 2.3.4. So, it's Airflow 2, right ?

Comment: @Matthias I inserted the AIRFLOW_URL variable inside this field (I said this at the middle of the question), but I tried other ways to use the command, none of them worked. –